# Building a jolt transformation that duplicates values

Tags: json, transformation, jolt

I'm trying to build a jolt transformer that goes from

```
{
  "name": "name",
  "tags": [
    "value1",
    "value2"
  ]
}
```

(for n values) to

```
{
  "options": [
    {
      "key": "value1",
      "value": "value1"
    },
    {
      "key": "value2",
      "value": "value2"
    }
  ]
}
```

I've tried a bunch of variants, and I can move the items of the input array into various parts of the output, but I can't figure out how to duplicate the value of the array item into the object in the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Description inline:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      //match tags
      "tags": {
       //for each item in array
        "*": {
          //Use value from the array (@) and set it as key and value
          //Using array position in [&1]
          "@": ["options.[&1].key", "options.[&1].value"]
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```